# interaction of two classes, python

Tags: python, class

I am very new to Python and objected oriented programming. So please excuse if I am asking a stupid question:
The following is supposed to be a simple text editor. I WANT to have the textfield and the menu bar in separate classes. Current error message is:

```
  File "Editor_play.py", line 19, in __init__
    menubar = Menu(window)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

My question:

1. do I have to call an object of Textfield and an object of Menu as I did or should I call an object Textfield and have to call the Menu from inside Textfield?
2. how do I get the Menu to know about `self.text` in Textfield?

thank you in anticipation.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog

class Textfield(object):
  def __init__(self, window):
    self.window = window
    window.title("text editor")
    self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(window)
    self.scrollbar.pack(side="right",fill="y")
    self.text = Text(window,yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
    self.scrollbar.config(command=self.text.yview)
    self.text.pack()
    window.mainloop()


class Menu(object):   
  def __init__(self, window):
    self.window = window
    menubar = Menu(window)
    filemenu = Menu(menubar)
    filemenu.add_command(label="load",command=self.load)
    filemenu.add_command(label="save as",command=self.saveas)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="file",menu=filemenu)
    window.config(menu=menubar)

  def load(self):
    self.file = tkFileDialog.askopenfile()
    self.text.delete(1.0, END)
    if self.file:
      self.text.insert(1.0, self.file.read())

  def saveas(self):
    self.file = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile()
    if self.file:
      self.file.write(self.text.get(1.0, END))


window =  Tk()            
textfield = Textfield(window)
menu = Menu(window)
```

---

now it looks like this and it still isn't right.

reason for the menu class is that i want to understand how this works in general. and because i could have another app with the same menu and then I would put the menu class into a module.

on my way to learing how to programme with python, this understanding of interaction between these two example classes seems to be a milestone for me. ones i have understood, i can go on. i earlier asked in another post if i can actually make mistakes or create dead ends when structuring (into classes). the answers were: everything is possible, no restrictions. now i want to apply this to this example. please help.

current error message is:

```
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Editor_play.py", line 41, in <module>
    menu = Menubar(window, textfield.text)
  File "Editor_play.py", line 20, in __init__
    menubar = Menu(window)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2580, in __init__
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1974, in __init__
_tkinter.TclError: this isn't a Tk applicationNULL main window
"""



from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog

class Textfield(object):
  def __init__(self, window):
    self.window = window
    window.title("text editor")
    self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(window)
    self.scrollbar.pack(side="right",fill="y")
    self.text = Text(window,yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
    self.scrollbar.config(command=self.text.yview)
    self.text.pack()
    window.mainloop()


class Menubar(object):   
  def __init__(self, window, text):
    self.window = window
    self.text = text
    menubar = Menu(window)
    filemenu = Menu(menubar)
    filemenu.add_command(label="load",command=self.load)
    filemenu.add_command(label="save as",command=self.saveas)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="file",menu=filemenu)
    window.config(menu=menubar)

  def load(self):
    self.file = tkFileDialog.askopenfile()
    self.text.delete(1.0, END)
    if self.file:
      self.text.insert(1.0, self.file.read())

  def saveas(self):
    self.file = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile()
    if self.file:
      self.file.write(self.text.get(1.0, END))


window =  Tk()            
textfield = Textfield(window)
menu = Menubar(window, textfield.text)
```

Comment: In `Menu` you reference `self.text` but you don't define it anywhere in there.

Comment: Your `Menu` class creates a *new* instance of `Menu`, which then creates a new instance of `Menu`, ad infinitum. Well, at least until the RecursionError. What are the nested `Menu` objects supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Menu` class overwrites the `Tkinter` menu class. Rename it to something else and you won't have this issue.

The way to let menu know about `Textfield` is to pass your `Textfield` instance into the menu class constructor as an argument. Better yet, if all you're doing is writing a simple text editor, you wouldn't really need to have separate classes for `Menu` and `Textfield`. You could just have an "app" class that subclasses the root object.

Comment: ok I have changed the name of the class. even though the script is small, i want to separate into two classes, because i want to understand how this works in general.